# the div tag is displaying when refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, html

In this below code i have text box and submit button  .when i enter or refresh that page the div tag displays but my expected result is when i enter a value in textbox and click submit button then div tag should appear.The problem is div tag  displays always. Please any one help me.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('search1_site/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">
    <input type="text" name = "keyword" />
    <input type="submit" id="opn" value = "Search" />
</form>
<div id='hideme'>
    <strong>Warning:</strong>These are new products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close'>
        <img src="images/close_icon.gif" width="6" height="6" alt="Close" onClick="hide('hideme')"/>
    </a>
    <div style="background:#669900; width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -100px" id="modal" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>course_code</th>
                <th>course name</th>
            </tr>
    <?php foreach($results as $row):?>
            <tr>
                <center>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $row->course_code?>
                    </td>
                </center>
                <center>
                    <td>
                    <?php echo $row->course_name?>
                    </td>
                </center>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?> 
        </table></div></div>
    </div>
<script>
    $('a.modal').bind('click', function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#modal').fadeIn(10);
    });
    function hide(obj) {
        var el = document.getElementById(obj);
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Which div you want to show and hide. There are two div's.

Comment: this div should display when i submit    <div style="background:#669900; width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -100px" id="modal" >

Comment: Please explain your issue properly to get better answers.

Comment: when i submit a value the div should display in other times it should not display

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to say that mixing JQuery with traditional javascript is not very efficient.. Instead of using getElementById you can use $('#' + obj).val()...
In your problem I guess the most efficient solution would be to use JQuery's .hide() and .show() methods to hide and unhide divs....
You can try this :

```
function hide(obj) {
    var el = $('#' + obj).val();
    e1.hide();
}
```

Also if you want any div to be hidden as soon as the page is loaded, you can use the hide method in $(document).ready(){}... To show it anytime you can use e1.show() method...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to hide your div through css usign `display:none;`. You haven't set this that is why your div is showing on page load.

Your div should looks like

```
 <div style="background:#669900; width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -100px;display:none;" id="modal" >
```

Call a function on form submit. Your `<form>` tag should looks like

```
<form onSubmit="return showDiv();" action="<?php echo site_url('search1_site/search_keyword');?>" method = "post">
```

And your javascript function will looks like

```
function showDiv() {
    $('#modal').fadeIn(10);
    return false; //not to refresh page

}
```

Comment: when i set display:none; it doesn't show the div when i enter the value in textbox and submit @Awais Qarni

Comment: @moses Open firebug in firefox browser and check if there is any error?

Answer (score 0):

First add `display:none;` to the div whom you want to be hidden,

add attribute

```
onsubmit="return validate()"

function validate()
{
  //validate the form as you want

  document.getElementById('modal').style.display="block";

  return false ; // if you dont want to submit the form

}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is an css style `<style>#hideme{display:none}</style>`